# Typo3 can't find page in back-end, but I can find it if I google it

Tags: typo3

I have a typo3 back-end. I just got a mail that on our site it private information of a former client and he send me a link. Shockingly it's true that there is his information, but I can't find it anywhere in my back-end. I have to say that I am quite new to typo3 and this position as well. Any help or guidance how to find that actual page would be lovely.

If you need anymore information, feel free to ask!

I already tried to locate it in the specific pages and folders in my back-end, hoping I would find it there, but I wasn't lucky. When you google the title of the link you can actually find it on google, but I cant find it on my back-end

Comment: Does Google only list it in their results? Or can you follow the link to your website, where it is also shown? Does your website use any cache/proxy (e.g. EXT:static_file_cache), which responds before passing the request to TYPO3?

Comment: When I pretty much google the h1 of the website, it shows up on google and actually leads to my website. I don't know about the proxy, but I don't think so.

Comment: So, the content is shown on *your* website? Or is only left in Google's indexing cache?

Comment: The content is shown on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Get a database dump and look for the information of this 'lost' page.

If you have content you can look in the table `tt_content`, fields `header` or `bodytext`, or in the table `pages`, field `title` for the page name. (the text could be stored in different fields and tables, but those are the most common places)

As TYPO3 has multiple ways to disable content you could try to find the data first and then decide which disabling mechanism has failed.

If the data is not available in your DB you need to look elsewhere (like caches, proxies or even exported files (there is an extension to cache generated files as static files in the filesystem))

'deleted' data in TYPO3 is not really deleted but only marked as `deleted`. So a record could be recovered (which can be done with the `recycler` extension).

Another way to hide data **in the Backend** is if data is versioned or stored in a workspace. If the data has flags for versions or workspaces and afterwards the extension for handling versioning is disabled those records could become visible as the restrictions/ filters could be disabled also.
*This should be detectable if the records still exists in the database.*

Answer (score 0):

did you try to clear caches? Maybe something is stucked threre?!

Best,
Chris

Comment: Please add more information to your answer: Which cache? How to clear? So your answer will help others.

Comment: This is not really an answer and you should state in a comment next time.